# C Makefile, Strange error with "No target" when a target is present

Tags: c, makefile

So I have the makefile

```
HEADERS = preferences.h distances.h
OBJECTS = movie_recommender.o preferences.o distances.o

default: movie_recommender

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    ; gcc -c $< -o $@

movie_recommender: $(OBJECTS)
    ; gcc $(OBJECTS) -o $@

clean:
    ; -rm -f $(OBJECTS)
    ; -rm -f movie_recommender
```

And I receive the error:

```
No rule to make target 'movie_recommender.o', needed by 'movie_recommender'. Stop.
```

[File paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M6pj.png)
I've tried adding the target,

```
movie_recommender.o: movie_recommender.c
    gcc -c movie_recommender.c
```

And I receive another error. Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: What does `ls` give you in the makefile's directory? EDIT: Oh, I see your paths. It's easier if information is included in the question, not in a linked image.

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't know how to include the paths other than in an image :(

Comment: The problem is a disagreement between your makefile and your directory structure (which you could have described in text). The simplest fix is to add the line `vpath %.c src` to your makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `make` program only looks in *the current directory* for your files. There is no `movie_recommender.c` file in the current directory, so `make` doesn't see it and doesn't find any way to make `movie_recommender.o`.

The solution is to add make your makefile aware of the source and header directories, which you can do [with the `vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Selective-Search.html#Selective-Search). If you add

```
vpath %.c src
```

then it will automatically look for `%.c` files in the `src` directory.

Similarly, `make` won't find your headers.

GCC also won't find the headers, and it can't know about `make`'s `vpath`, so instead you need to pass `-Iinclude` to GCC.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much!